# Xcode autoCompletion

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

is there a way to see only the direct properties of an instance?

it shows me every method and property that an instance has including all it's base classes. i wonder if i can set xcode to show me the direct properties first?

for instance: an EKEvent instance. i want to know what properties it has without using the cmd+click to go into it's h file. it shows me a long list of inherited properties which are hard to navigate through.

does anybody have an idea how to make it easier?

[image: an xcode autocomplete example]

Comment: I've always found this annoying myself. I also wish the list was circular (I could go "up" from the top of the list and be at the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the right (just before the scroll bar) a question mark should appear and you'd be able to click on it.
You can also do an Alt+click is the object is already written in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with current version. I hope Apple will implement it in future.